# Combining Data from raster and polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, polygon, overlay

I am teaching myself GIS at the moment, and there are still some matters I haven't quite got the hang of.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1, and have three datasets:

- LAYER 1: A population dataset at a high resolution, as a tiff raster. (Edit: the convert to polygon tool does not work on this raster)
- LAYER 2: A polygon layer, created as a fishnet, of equal squares, defined by two vectors.
- LAYER 3: An outline of the coastline.

What I need to do is to calculate the total population within a buffer of distance X km from the coastline for each polygon defined by the fishnet, that falls on the coastline.

I am currently struggling to combine the population data with that of the polygon layer however - any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following workflow:

1. [Buffer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//000800000019000000) your coastline feature
2. [Intersect](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000p000000) the buffered coastline with the fishnet polygons
3. Run [Zonal Statistics as Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000w8000000) with a "SUM" statistic
4. Use [Join Field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000065000000) to join the zonal statistics table with the intersected
   fishnet polygons (i.e. based on the OID or FID)

Comment: Hi - sounds good. Trying to use the intersect, but the output is empty, as fishnets don't contain any data - is another tool I can use for this?

Comment: The output should not be empty. Make sure the fishnet is in vector polygon format rather than polyline.

Comment: Just to clarify, the shape I was trying to buffer was too high a resolution, so my computer couldn't cope. Computationally this shouldn't be a problem if anyone reads this in the future!